# OpenCV convert all negative values to zero

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to implement a function that takes a `cv::Mat` and sets all negative values to zero. The most direct operation to do this appears to be the `threshold` function documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) so that the function `pos(x)`

```
void pos(cv::Mat x, cv::Mat result)
{           
    cv::threshold(x, result, 0, 0, CV_THRESH_TOZERO);
    return;
}
```

Is this the most appropriate way to set all negative values to zero or is there a faster or more direct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to `pass reference other than value`, and use `CV_THRESH_TRUNC`:

```
void pos(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst)
{           
    cv::threshold(-src, dst, 0, 0, CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
    dst = -dst;
    return;
}
```

Test:

```
[-3, -2, -1;
 0, 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 2]
```

---

**Update**:

@Steve suggest to use `cv::max(x,0)` to trunc the matrix. After test, it's better.

```
void pos(Mat& src, Mat& dst){
    dst = cv::max(src, 0);
    return void;
}
```

Comment: Is `CV_THRESH_TRUNC` recommended for speed? It seems like `result = cv::max(x,0)` is more concise but I'm unsure about speed if `x`  is both the input and result (self assignment of the result when calling `pos(x,x)`).

Comment: @Steve Wow, your idea is better. I just use threshold as the poster. I'll test

Comment: cv::max is faster than threshed method that I used.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way of neglecting all the negative numbers, by converting your matrix data type from signed to unsigned as:

```
char data[] = {-1, -2, 8, 4};
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(2, 2, CV_8SC1, data);

m.convertTo(m, CV_8UC1);

>>>  0, 0, 8, 4,
```

Comment: This is interesting but would not be functional for many types of data including floats and 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be viable(?):

```
void pos(Mat& src, Mat& dst){
    dst = 0.5*(cv::abs(src) + src);
    return void;
}
```